# What happened to Paolo and the Transmuters at the end of Diaspora?

Tags: hard-sci-fi, greg-egan

Greg Egan's Diaspora. At the end of the book, after Paolo and Yatima traveled up 267,904,176,383,054 levels of universes, where there were no more gateways to go through another level:

> Paolo’s gestalt seemed to hover between comic agony over the failure of their search, and sheer exaltation at its completion.

Where were the Transmuters? Did P & Y succeed in their search or not? If the Transmuters were not there, what does it mean to say:

> Paolo closed his eyes, and followed the Transmuters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Transmuters were gone - they had explored, experienced and analyzed the multiverse to their complete satisfaction and then allowed themselves to die:

> "What now? Where do we look for them?"
>
> [...] He said, "We look right in front of us."
>
> "There's nothing in front of us."
>
> "Not now. Because it's over. We've seen it all."
>
> "I don't understand."
>
> [...] "The artifacts were polises.  [...]
>
> "Then why did they stop?"
>
> "Because there was nothing more to do." [...] "They'd seen everything they wanted to see in the outside world

And Paolo does the same - he basically commits suicide, except he instead sees it as achieving completion because he's done all he wanted to do:

> "It won't be death." Paolo seemed calm now, perfectly resolved. "The Transmuters didn't die; they played out every possibility within themselves. And I believe I've done the same, back in U-double-star… or maybe I'm still doing it, somewhere. But I've found what I came to find, here. There's nothing more for me. That's not death. It's completion."

Basically, it's a transhumanist version of this ([source](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/dog_paradox)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you or somebody help me put a Greg Egan or Diaspora tag on this question? My reputation is too low to create new tags.